# What does 'self.class.class_method_name' in the initialize method do?

Tags: ruby

Do I need to put it in context or can someone give me a general overview? I've tried to do my own googling but am not coming up with enough info.

The part that confuses me is the "class" part. I understand self.class_method_name but not
self.class_method_name.

Comment: It would help if you could explain what, *precisely* is unclear to you about [the documentation of `Kernel#class`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-class). That way, you avoid us repeating things you already know, or repeating things you already read und didn't understand. Also, it would help the Ruby developers improve the documentation if you could tell them what's wrong with it. That way, future developers don't stumble over the same problems you did. Make the world a better place!

Answer (score 0):

`self` refers to the current instance of the class, `self.class` refers to the class of the instance.

For example:

```rb
class Person
  def initialize
    p self
    p self.class
  end
end

Person.new
```

This code would show:

```
#<Person:0x0000558351934020>
Person the class
```

The first line is the instance of `Person`, the second is the class per se.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when you define a method in class, it's instance of class, it mean you can only call it by object, ex:

```
class a
  define method_x
  end
end
```

, if you want to call method_x, you can only call by:

```
obj = a.new
obj.method_x
```

and you can not call : `a.method_x`

but when you define self.method_x, you can call it by class

```
class a
  define self.method_x
  end
end

a.method_x
```

, you can try as above and see result